# how to force gradle dependencies artifact version

Tags: gradle

Now I am using this code to force version in Gradle 6.0.1:

```
configurations.all {
        
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'redis.clients') {
                    details.useVersion "3.0.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.jsqlparser') {
                    details.useVersion "2.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.squareup.okhttp3') {
                    details.useVersion "4.0.0"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.pagehelper') {
                    
                    details.useVersion("5.1.11")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it works fine, but now there is a problem that I have many dependencies start with `com.github.pagehelper`, is there any way to using the group name and artifact name to force the version? I have already tried this way:

```
if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.pagehelper' && !details.requested.module == 'pagehelper') {
                   
                    details.useVersion("5.1.11")
                }
```

seems it does not work.

[image]

when I compile, this is the output:

```
+ ./gradlew :soa-illidan-multipipeline_master:soa-illidan-service:build -x test

> Configure project :soa-robot-multibranch_master
version info:1.0.0-RELEASE
> Task :soa-illidan-multipipeline_master:soa-illidan-service:generateLombokConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :soa-illidan-multipipeline_master:soa-illidan-service:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':soa-illidan-multipipeline_master:soa-illidan-service:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':soa-illidan-multipipeline_master:soa-illidan-service:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.pagehelper:pagehelper-spring-boot-starter:5.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :soa-illidan-multipipeline_master:soa-illidan-service > com.sportswin.soa:soa-illidan-api:1.0.33-RELEASE > com.sportswin.misc:soa-misc:1.0.13-RELEASE
      > Could not resolve com.github.pagehelper:pagehelper-spring-boot-starter:5.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/github/pagehelper/pagehelper-spring-boot-starter/5.2.0/pagehelper-spring-boot-starter-5.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/github/pagehelper/pagehelper-spring-boot-starter/5.2.0/pagehelper-spring-boot-starter-5.2.0.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 5.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I do it like this:

```
resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.pagehelper' && details.requested.name == 'pagehelper' ) {
                    
                    details.useVersion("5.2.0")
                }
            }
        }
```